# Connecting my monitor to HDMI connection on my GPU make it behave like a TV

Tags: display, graphics-card, hdmi, dvi

I have an HD5750 with a DVI and HDMI connections, I also have LG W2261V monitor that has DVI and HDMI connections.

I want to buy a new monitor but it doesn't have a DVI connection, now when I try to connect my current monitor using HDMI, the picture doesn't fill the whole screen, even when I set the resolution to 1080p, the quality is bad too.

Also, in AMD catlyst control center the monitor show up as a TV when connected through the HDMI port.

Is there a way to make the GPU to treat the monitor connected through the HDMI port as a monitor and not a TV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the Overscan in your CCC (Catalyst Control Center)

1. Open the Catalyst Control Center
2. My Digital Flat Panels
3. Scaling Options
4. change to 0% and apply

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Yeah that fixed the size. I also disconnected the DVI cable and now there's no artifacting and strange behavior, but it still show up as DTV in CCC, is that normal? Will it still behave like a monitor?

Comment: Yes it does. Thats normal.